# Duplicate pictureboxes C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two groups of Pictureboxes `Pic_1 Pic_2 ...` and another group: `Pic_1_copy, Pic_2_copy, ...`.

What i'd like to have for example 3 or more copies of `Pic_1`. So: `Pic_1_copy_1, Pic_1_copy_2, Pic_1_copy_3.`

Is there any simple way without messing in code for doing this? Instead of doing this in code:

```
Pic_1.Image = new Bitmap(Logo);
Pic_1_copy_1.Image = Pic_1.Image; 
Pic_1_copy_2.Image = Pic_1.Image;
Pic_1_copy_3.Image = Pic_1.Image;
      ...= Pic_1.Image;
```

I searched events of `Picturebox`, but i couldn't find something like: ImageChanged Event..

EDIT:

So i'm asking is there any option to create new Picturebox and assign to it image from Pic_1. So when Pic_1 image will be changed, this new picturebox will automaticaly change it's image to image from Pic_1.

Comment: Tell us what problem you are trying to solve instead of asking for that last 10% of your proposed solution.

Comment: Use an array or a collection of some kind such as a List or Dictionary.

Comment: I've added explanation of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any event for that either, i don't know if that is the best way, but i would try using the [LoadCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.loadcompleted.aspx) event.

that means you will have to try using the LoadAsync method.

another way is using the Location property to change the picture and for that you have an event.

One more thing you can try is to create a new class and derive from the PictureBox class.
then you can create an event for setting Image (by wrapping the Image property on the new class)

**UPDATE:** i found that after a little search: [Is there an event for an image change for a PictureBox Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551339/is-there-an-event-for-an-image-change-for-a-picturebox-control)

Comment: Yea, but the Paint event will occure even when you minimize/maximize/move/etc the window... i don't think you want that

Comment: look at the update, someone already did a good job showing how to implement the derived class