# How to detect whether pictureBox successfully displayed the image or not?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, validation, picturebox

I have a `pictureBox` that loads an image directly from the internet. The image can change dynamically and is specified by the user in a `textBox` that has a `TextChanged` event that changes the image in `pictureBox` to the URL in the `textBox`. When user clicks the submit button, the image URL is saved in the database. But before saving I want to validate the image, that whether the image displayed successfully or the error image is displayed in place of it. So how can I validate this?

Comment: check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551339/is-there-an-event-for-an-image-change-for-a-picturebox-control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the LoadComplete event to see when it has changed, and if the eventArg's error is null (successful) or not null (fail).

```
void pictureBox1_LoadCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Error != null)
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ToString());
}

this.pictureBox1.Validated += new EventHandler(pictureBox1_Validated);
this.pictureBox1.ImageLocation = this.textBox1.Text;
```

-
Edit: Just saw Dips' comment, did not use that link but is same means to answer this.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I actually wanted :)

Answer (score 2):

Place the code below in the function where you are retrieving the path of image from textBox ,be sure to place it before you do anything else on that path;

```
    string path = "Path to image";
    Bitmap bmp;//To validate the Image.
    try
    {
        bmp = new Bitmap(path);//Create a Bitmap object from the given path.
        if (bmp != null)
        {
            pictureBox1.Load(path);//Display the image to the user.
            //Now it's safe to store the image path in the database,
            //because we have validated it.
            bmp.Dispose();//Dispose the Bitmap object to free occupied resources.
            //Place you database related code here which uses the path we just validated.
        }

    }

    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The specified image file is invalid.");
        //Show error image in PictureBox. 
        //(pictureBox1.Image="Path to error image").
        //Don't store image path,its invalid.
    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The path to image is invalid.");
        //Show error image in PictureBox. 
        //(pictureBox1.Image="Path to error image").
        //Don't store image path,its invalid.
    }
```

When you've done this you can place your code where I've shown the comment **//Place your database...**.This ensures that the file path and image is validated before anything else uses them.`This method also checks if the image file is actually an image and not a **.txt** or **.exe** with its extension changed to **.jpg** or any other image format,as you've mentioned in your comments you need to check if the path actually points to an image file.

You can the extend the exception handling mechanism if you need something more than displaying a `MessageBox` with error information.One more thing that is worth to be mentioned is that,`before you display any image or do anything you will have to check if the url is valid one,to simplify this step you can try to download the file(it can be anything - an image,an executable,a text file or at least a web page,when it has been downloaded pass the path to that file(relative to filesystem) to this function.`

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose Pic1 is name of your control. To validate then you can use simply,

```
if(pic1.ImageLocation.Trim().Length>4)   // > 4 since a shortest valid image 
                                            file will be a.png or something 
                                            similar; length= 5
{
   if(validExtensions(pic1.ImageLocation)
    {
       //then put the path to database
    }
}
```

**Updated**

```
//Mehod to valid image extensions
private bool validExtensions(string url)
{
   var imgs = new []{".jpg",".gif",".png",".bmp",".jpeg"};
   var ext = System.IO.Path.GetFileExtention(url); // see the correct method
                                                       in intellisense
    if(imgs.Contains(ext)
      return false;
}
```

Update 2

```
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
dialog.Filter =  "Image files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.jpe, *.jfif, *.png) | *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.jfif; *.png";
        dialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
        dialog.Title = "Please select an image file to encrypt.";
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //Encrypt the selected file. I'll do this later. :)
        }
```

Comment: But what if the user gives this `http://www.somedomain.com/images/r.htm` or an image file that is not supported by the pictureBox?

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva see my updated answer. Thanks for pointing out the missing part

Comment: but still the problem is not solved. Your solution will work well but it is totally depended on the filename or the URL. So if someone just for some prank renamed a text file "ABC.TXT" to "ABC.JPG" and added its URL to the TextBox. The form will still be validated and that URL will be saved in the database. When some one else opens this image, it will show error image. But I want to stop this before posting.

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva , Then I think , You need to make your textbox readonly or disabled with a open file dialog box and in open file dilog box, filter images only. Search for OpenFileDialog . See updated ans

Comment: as I stated in my question that the image is fetched from internet and the user enteres the URL in the textBox. So I can't use OpenFileDialog for it.