# Do something once a picturebox is loaded

Tags: c#, forms

I have a method that generates 50 `PictureBox`es and puts them in an array

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
  pb[i] = new PictureBox();
  pb[i].Name = "pictureBox" + i.ToString();
  pb[i].Location = new Point(xPos, yPos);
  pb[i].Size = new Size(100, 50);
  pb[i].BackColor = Color.Black;
  pb[i].Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
  pb[i].Click += (sender, ex) => this.shot();
  panel1.Controls.Add(pb[i]);
}
```

I load them on the screen by using a timer. It's loading every element in the array at every second or so.

My question is how can I do something to a `PictureBox` ONLY when has loaded?
I've tried with the `WaitOnLoad`, but it doesn't seem the right thing.
For example I want to move the `PictureBox` on the "X" axys (to the right) once it's generated.

Comment: What do you mean by "has loaded"? The form has a `Load` event, but the picturebox does not.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention ( will edit). Once the pictureboxes are generated and put in an array I have a timer to display them on the screen once every second or so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an event for an image change for a PictureBox Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551339/is-there-an-event-for-an-image-change-for-a-picturebox-control)

Comment: There should be no need to do that over and over with a timer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment:

> Once the pictureboxes are generated and put in an array I have a timer to display them on the screen once every second or so.

One option would certainly be to let the code in the timer do what you want. If you don't like that, every control, including the picture box has a [VisibleChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.visiblechanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) event to which you can subscribe so you can do something when it is shown or hidden.